How can I "flatten" a true multi-dimensional array to old "simulated" gawk array?
I have gawk's (4.++) true multi-dimensional array I'd like to "flatten" (convert to the OLD/simulated - pre-gawk 4.x) array.
arr["a"]["a"] = 21
arr["a"]["b"] = 21
arr["b"]["a"] = 2
arr["b"]["b"] = 3
arr["c"]["a"] = 4

converted to
arrFlat["a", "a"] = 21
arrFlat["a", "b"] = 21
arrFlat["b", "a"] = 2
arrFlat["b", "b"] = 3
arrFlat["c", "a"] = 4

I've been looking into multiple threads dealing with multi-dimensional arrays including this
and others dealing with walk_array etc.
I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I cannot figure out the proper recursive call to convert one array presentation to the other. I need this to ease the "sorting by value" (numeric or otherwise) of the multi-dimensional arrays.
Obviously the index "depth" of the array (source arr) is not limited to 2 as in the example.
Any golden nuggets anyone can share, pls!

consider updating the question with your attempt(s) at modifying the walk_array() function; also, please update the question with details on where the multi-dimensional array is coming from (eg, is it hardcoded in a BEGIN{} block? is it being built from an input data set? something else?)

@markp-fuso, ok - I've updated the OP with the proper quoted strings as indicies to BOTH arrays - just to make sure it properly exemplifies the structure.
The true multi dimensional array gets populated by parsing the syslog files for further analysis where the indices are derived from some fields in the syslog AND the values are computed/aggregated/etc by gawk itself .
But it shouldn't matter - just an example.
Looking at the copy_array by Ed Morton  and cannot think of how to massage into into "flattening" instead of "copying" array.
Hoped I could get a nudge in the right direction.

sounds like the 'easier' approach may be to modify the original gawk code to generate both arrays (arr[], arrFlat[]) at the same time since the code (obviously?) has access to the indices at that point; as for a nudge ... you'll want to look at building the compound index by passing the 'current' compound index to the function and then appending the next level index onto the end of said compound index which in turn is then passed to the next function call (Duh, Mark! ?)

you improve your chances of receiving assistance if you show your (coding) efforts, otherwise there's a good chance the question will be closed due to needing more details, clarity or focus

What do you mean by 'I need this to ease the "sorting by value" (numeric or otherwise) of the multi-dimensional arrays.'? It sounds like that is your real problem and converting the array is your idea of a solution rather than the actual problem you're trying to solve but maybe there's some better approach to solving that problem than flattening the array. You might want to ask a question about that.

I think I found a way to massage @EdMorton "copy_array" implemntation, into something that "flattens" the true multi-dimensional array:
$ cat flatten.awk
BEGIN {
    arr["a"]["a"] = 21
    arr["a"]["b"] = 21
    arr["b"]["a"] = 2
    arr["b"]["b"] = 3
    arr["c"]["a"] = 4
    arr["d"]["x"]["y"]= 90
    arr["d"]["x"]["z"]= 95


    walk_array(arr, "arr")

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"
    flatten_array(arr, flatten)

    print "----------"

    walk_array(flatten, "flatten")
}

function flatten_array(orig, flatten, idx,      i)
{
    for (i in orig) {
        if (isarray(orig[i])) {
            flatten_array(orig[i], flatten, (idx=="" && idx==0) ? i : (idx SUBSEP i) )
        }
        else {
            #printf("idx->[%s]\n", idx) > "/dev/stderr"
            flatten[idx SUBSEP i] = orig[i]
        }
    }
}

function walk_array(arr, name,      i)
{
    for (i in arr) {
        if (isarray(arr[i]))
            walk_array(arr[i], (name "[" i "]"))
        else
            printf("%s[%s] = %s\n", name, i, arr[i])
    }
}

$ gawk -f flatten.awk
arr[a][a] = 21
arr[a][b] = 21
arr[b][a] = 2
arr[b][b] = 3
arr[c][a] = 4
arr[d][x][y] = 90
arr[d][x][z] = 95
----------
flatten[ba] = 2
flatten[bb] = 3
flatten[ca] = 4
flatten[aa] = 21
flatten[ab] = 21
flatten[dxy] = 90
flatten[dxz] = 95

Not particularly graceful, but...
Unless someone else can offer an alternative...

not sure you'll be able to get 'more' graceful given that you have to recursively 'unbuild' the indices of a multi-dimensional array; building the flattened array at the same time you build the original array will probably be as graceful as you can get; since flatten[] is a single-dimensional array you could forego the walk_array() call for a single for i in flatten printf ... loop; having said that ... it works and if users understand how walk_array() and copy_array() work then this is an easy-to-understand solution; kudos

Looks good but "" is a valid value for an array index so instead of the first call being flatten_array(arr, flatten, "") and then testing for it with (length(idx) ? (idx SUBSEP i) : i) you should make the first call flatten_array(arr, flatten) and then the test becomes (idx=="" && idx==0 ? i : (idx SUBSEP i)). You might want to name your flattened array flat instead of flatten just for slightly improved clarity.

@EdMorton all valid comments - appreciate it!

@EdMorton : idx=="" && idx==0 - an array cannot simultaneously have both the empty string only ("") and also the null value ( idx == "" && idx == 0 ) as indices (otherwise arr[""] or ("" in arr) become ambiguous syntax), so IIRC just testing against empty string alone suffices. (but pairing (1) numeric or string zero, with (2) empty string or null value, is perfectly fine)

@RAREKpopManifesto an array can't since all array indices are strings, but a function argument can and the OP was using idx == "" as a test for first vs subsequent calls to the function by calling the function with idx set to "" as an argument which can't work since "" is a valid array index.

Using the standard walk_array() function as a template for a new flatten_array() function:
awk '
BEGIN { #### sample multi-dimensional array

        arr["a"]["a"] = 21
        arr["a"]["b"] = 21
        arr["b"]["a"] = 2
        arr["b"]["b"] = 3
        arr["c"]["a"] = 4
        arr["d"] = 19
        arr["e"]["f"]["g"]["h"] = 14

        flatten_array(arr, "arr")

        #### OP mentions needing to sort the (flattened) array by value ...

        print "############ @val_num_desc"

        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"                 # sort arrFlat[] by numeric value in descending order
        for (ndx in arrFlat)
            printf "arrFlat[%s] = %s\n", ndx,arrFlat[ndx]

        print "############ @val_num_asc"

        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"                  # sort arrFlat[] by numeric value in ascending order
        for (ndx in arrFlat)
            printf "arrFlat[%s] = %s\n", ndx,arrFlat[ndx]
      }

function flatten_array(arr, name, ndx,     i)
{
    for (i in arr) {
        new_ndx = ndx (ndx=="" ? "" : ",") i                    # "," is a literal comma; replace "," with SUBSEP if you wish to use the system default delimiter
        if (isarray(arr[i]))
            flatten_array(arr[i], (name "[" i "]"), new_ndx )
        else
            arrFlat[new_ndx] = arr[i]
    }
}
'

NOTES:

re: index delimiter - comma vs SUBSEP:
new_ndx = ndx (ndx=="" ? "" : ",") i - this uses a literal comma as the index delimiter which in turn is visible when printing the array indices
new_ndx = ndx (ndx=="" ? "" : SUBSEP) i - this will use awk's standard index delimiter character \034 however it typically does not show up when printed to stdout
"a" SUBSEP "b" will typically display as ab but if you pipe this through od -c you will see a \034 b
if the indices will not contain commas then OP should be able to use either delimiter (comma, SUBSEP) based on display (stdout) requirements
re: target array name:
the target array name (arrFlat[]) is hardcoded in the flatten_array() function
parameterization of the target array name is left as an exercise for the reader
hint: see the copy_array() function or OP's answer for an approach to parameterizing array names

This generates:
############ @val_num_desc
arrFlat[a,b] = 21
arrFlat[a,a] = 21
arrFlat[d] = 19
arrFlat[e,f,g,h] = 14
arrFlat[c,a] = 4
arrFlat[b,b] = 3
arrFlat[b,a] = 2
############ @val_num_asc
arrFlat[b,a] = 2
arrFlat[b,b] = 3
arrFlat[c,a] = 4
arrFlat[e,f,g,h] = 14
arrFlat[d] = 19
arrFlat[a,a] = 21
arrFlat[a,b] = 21


@markp_fuso , thanks - pretty much the same I approach I took.
Appreciate the effort!

Similar comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79135135/how-can-i-flatten-a-true-multi-dimensional-array-to-old-simulated-gawk-array#comment139543033_79135352 regarding ndx=="". You could also consider setting SUBSEP="," then using SUBSEP instead of hard-coding "," and adding a comment to replace it with SUBSEP.

Assuming you don't need to be able to do this interactively, perhaps this is what you're looking for. I was trying to figure out how to pass the array as input to this script, as I don't think this works interactively, although maybe someone else can take this and improve it a bit.
EDIT: Okay I just wrote the shell script.
#!/bin/bash

# In case you need to do this programmatically 
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 '<input array to flatten>'"
    echo "Example: $0 'arr[\"a\"][\"a\"]=21; \
               arr[\"a\"][\"b\"]=21; arr[\"b\"][\"a\"]=2; \
               arr[\"b\"][\"b\"]=3; arr[\"c\"][\"a\"]=4; \
               arr[\"c\"][\"d\"][\"e\"]=10;'"
    exit 1
fi


array_definition="$1"

# Temporary file 
gawk_script="temp_flatten_sort.awk"

# create a temporary custom hardcoded script
cat << EOF > "$gawk_script"
# Recursive function to flatten multi-dimensional arrays
function flatten_array(src, dest, prefix, key, flat_key) {
    for (key in src) {
        if (isarray(src[key])) {
            flat_key = (prefix == "") ? key : prefix "," key
            flatten_array(src[key], dest, flat_key)
        } else {
            flat_key = (prefix == "") ? key : prefix "," key
            dest[flat_key] = src[key]
        }
    }
}

BEGIN {
   
    $array_definition

    delete flattened_array  # Initialize the flattened array

   
    flatten_array(arr, flattened_array)

    # Sort by values
    n = 0
    for (k in flattened_array) {
        n++
        keys[n] = k
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (flattened_array[keys[i]] > flattened_array[keys[j]]) {
                temp = keys[i]
                keys[i] = keys[j]
                keys[j] = temp
            }
        }
    }

    # Print
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        print "flattened_array[\"" keys[i] "\"] =", flattened_array[keys[i]]
    }
}
EOF

# exec
gawk -f "$gawk_script"
# cleanup
rm "$gawk_script"

Now, you can just run it:
$./flatten.sh 'arr["a"]["a"]=21; arr["a"]["b"]=21; arr["b"]["a"]=2; arr["b"]["b"]=3; arr["c"]["a"]=4; arr["c"]["d"]["e"]=10;'


thanks for sharing, @Chev_603 - similar to my try.

Eh the others are better.  i created a wrapper script so you can call this interactively tho. Hacks on top of hacks xD.
